# Creating a file and name it based on a input in c++

Tags: c++

How can I create a new file that has the same name as a file I'm taking as input in argv[] (extension included) and add another extension to it?
For instance if I take "hello.txt" as input in argv[1], how can I create a file and name it "hello.txt.out"?

Comment: Do you know how to open files? How to build strings?  Does your C++ book cover these topics?

Comment: Use a `std::string` and use one of its methods to append like operator+

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you change the filename extension stored in a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/757933/6045800)

Answer (score 3):

Many different ways to approach this:

```
std::string filename = std::string(argv[1]) + ".out";
```

```
std::string filename = argv[1];
filename += ".out";
```

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << argv[1] << ".out";
std::string filename = oss.str();
```

```
std::string filename = std::format("{}.out", argv[1]);
```

Just to name a few.

Answer (score 2):

`sts::string`, the common string type in C++, allows the `+` operator to signify *concatenation*.

```
std::string infile = argv[1];
std::string outfile = infile + ".out";
```

`std::string` is also accepted by the `std::fstream` constructor as a file path

```
std::ofstream the_file_i_am_creating(outfile);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw in an option using `string_literals` too. It may come in handy if you do this a lot.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    using namespace std::string_literals;

    if(argc < 2) return 1;

    // "filename" and "out"s are here `std::string`s:

    auto filename = argv[0] + ".out"s;

    std::ofstream os(filename);

    // ...
}
```